# Cannot get the value from my radio buttons / checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, radio-button

```js
createIrecButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting

  // get the form by its id
  const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

  // get the input elements from the form
  const inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll("input");

  // create an empty object to store the input values
  const data = {};

  // loop through the input elements
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {
  // get the input name and value
  const name = input.name;
  let value = "";

  // check if input is a radio button
  if (input.type === "radio") {
    // check if input is disabled or unchecked
    if (input.disabled || !input.checked) {
      value = "";
    } else {
      value = input.value;
    }
  } else if (input.tagName === "SELECT") {
    // check if input is disabled or no option selected
    if (input.disabled || input.selectedIndex === -1) {
      value = "";
    } else {
        value = input.options[input.selectedIndex].value;
    }
  } else if (input.type === "checkbox") {
    // checkbox input
    if (input.disabled || !input.checked) {
      value = "";
    } else {
      value = input.value;
    }
  } else {
    // input is not a radio button, checkbox, or select box
    value = input.value;
  }

  // add the name-value pair to the data object
  data[name] = value;
});
```

radio buttons are initially disabled but are enabled later. even when a radio button is checked I'm still just returning the value of "". Sorry I'm very new.
Here's an example of one a couple of the radio buttons:

```html
<input
  id="phone1typeMobile"
  type="radio"
  name="phoneType1"
  value="Cell phone - "
  style="margin-right: 0"
  disabled        
/><label for="phone1typeMobile">M</label>
      
<input
  id="phone1typeLandline"
  type="radio"
  name="phoneType1"
  value="Landline - "
  style="margin-right: 0"
  disabled
/><label for="phone1typeLandline">L</label>
```

Looking to get the values pushed into my object instead of just returning ""
can't seem to figure out why it doesn't record the value. if you need more information please let me know. this is my first coding project.

Comment: bad way to code that, use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of radio and checkbox input types. Reading e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio may help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would expect a form to work in a case like this. Use the [FormData.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) and create your own object.

In this example I create two different objects (data1, data2). The first one just contains the key/values for input elements with a value. The second also has the keys (and an empty string) for input elements that has not been selected/without value.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get all the (not disabled) data from the form
  let formData = new FormData(e.target);
  // create data object
  let data1 = {};
  // run through all entries and add to data object
  [...formData.entries()].forEach(entry => {
    data1[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  });
  console.log(data1);
  // if you need all the keys to be in the object
  // you can pre-populate the data object with empty values
  let data2 = {};
  [...e.target.elements].forEach(elm => {
    if (elm.name) data2[elm.name] = "";
  });
  // run through all entries and add to data object
  [...formData.entries()].forEach(entry => {
    data2[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  });
  console.log(data2);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="radio" name="phoneType1" value="Cell phone - " style="margin-right: 0" /><label for="phone1typeMobile">M</label>
  <input type="radio" name="phoneType1" value="Landline - " style="margin-right: 0" /><label for="phone1typeLandline">L</label>
  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></label>
  <label>Size: <select name="size">
  <option value="">Select a size</option>
  <option value="1">S</option>
  <option value="2">M</option>
  <option value="3">L</option>
  </select></label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Also of note: this answer moves to the `submit` event instead of binding to clicking the submit button. Not only does this allow access to the form's overall data, it *also* means that users can press `Enter` anywhere in the form to submit and the event handler will still run as expected!